# If StreamBuilder get null show Different widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up StreamBuilder to retrieve data from a specific user, but if the user still has not any data available I want to display a different widget.
How to do that?
here is my code:

```
class _CollectDataState extends State<CollectData> {
  final String phone;
  final String wife;
  final String location;

  _CollectDataState({this.phone, this.wife, this.location});

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 2,
          // ignore: missing_return
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int ) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    snapshot.data['phone'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            else{
              return NoData();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!=null){
      return ListView.builder(
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount: 2,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int ) {
            return Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
               children: <Widget>[
                     Text(snapshot.data['phone'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                         ),
               ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
    
    else{
       return NoData();
    }
  },
   
 ); 
}
```

Please refer here for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: in that way as error I get a non null String must be provided

Comment: thanks I edited above Nodata() is a Text Widget:
class Nodata extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Nessun Dato'),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Comment: also if I put  else{
            return "Error widget" got the same and I get: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("phone")

Comment: Please, share complete function.

Comment: Ok I tried to put al the code because I have limited code writing here..

Comment: I just asked to share your build function only, It's still incomplete

Comment: Thanks here is a Link to the code Shared: https://codeshare.io/5ZmDPX

Comment: Just rectified your code's build function. You were using the condition in wrong place. https://codeshare.io/5RK80j

Comment: Copying and paste the code I got error and first snapshot red underline: if(snapshot && snapshot.hasData)
so I remvoed the first snapshot and it return always error ( NotSuchMEthodError) the method [] was called on Null

Comment: also add one more condition, snapshot.data!=null, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hello where to put: snapshot.data!=null because I dont see that in the reply edited

Comment: Please, check now

Comment: In that Way finally I got the exception NoData widget but, even the snapshot has data, the widget NoData is displayed, thus the data into firestore cat be retrieved

Comment: Maybe you are getting empty list i.e [] in data.

Comment: if I remove if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!=null) data are there thats strange

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if statement` to check for that and return a different widget. Something like below should work.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamBuilder(
     stream: getData(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
           // you can show whatever you want here
           return Text("Nothing to show");
        }
        ....
     });
}
```

This is not the best solution as `snapshot.data` can be `null` while the data is being loaded.

Depending on what data you are getting, you might want to check `if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {..}` instead to differentiate between loading state and data not available state.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     
      return   snapshot?.data??false? Column(
        children: <Widget>[. //user data widget with data
         ]):Container();           //use any widget  like loader
```